# @MappedSuperclass : Persistent entity should have primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with Spring Data JPA and I'm trying to create 4 different entities that will have exactly the same fields but they will be stored in 4 different tables.

This is my key class

```
public class IndexId implements Serializable {

    private int seqNo;
    private String index;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then I have the base class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseIndex {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "seq_no", nullable = false)
    protected int seqNo;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "index", nullable = false)
    protected String index;

    @Column(name = "value", nullable = false)
    protected String value;

    //getters/setters
}
```

Then my entity that will store in the database:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(IndexId.class)
@Table(name = "bibliographic_single_index")
public class BibliographicSingleIndex extends BaseIndex implements Serializable { }
```

This is the error I get: `Persistent entity 'BibliographicSingleIndex' should have primary key` .
I also tried with the properties declared as `private` and the [articles](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) I see on this subject seem to do the same thing.

With these pieces of code is it possible to identify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you have something like  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "some_gen") above your @Id field?

Comment: @MrFisherman I tried and it's not that. Also, I set the IndexId for that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe every entity needs a separate java class for the id class. You wouldn't have the problem with embedded ids I think.